# Configure Azure App Registration to change Active Directory user password

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm create a service app that runs in the background and changes user's password in Azure Active Directory via Microsoft Graph API. Everything works fine if I give the Application `User administrator` or `Helpdesk administrator` role. What if I'm not allowed to user role but rather use "API Permissions" and give only permission to change password, nothing else?

I tried to add `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` and `Directory.ReadWrite.All` API permissions. Even tried to add other permissions. Here is a list of API permissions I had (I know that some of them are not needed, just wanted to do the process of elimination later):

[image]

But still getting 403 error

> "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied"
>
> "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

I'm using Python to achieve that. Here is my code that is working with the `Helpdesk administrator` role:

```
import json
import logging

import requests
import msal     # pip install msal
import jwt

user_id = 'max@abc.onmicrosoft.com'

tenant_id = 'AZURE TENANT ID'
client_id = 'AZURE CLIENT ID'
secret = 'AZURE CLIENT SECRET'

users_endpoint = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users'
scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']
authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/%s' % tenant_id


app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id,
    authority=authority,
    client_credential=secret
)

# Get access token
result = app.acquire_token_silent(scopes=scopes, account=None)

if not result:
    logging.debug("No suitable token exists in cache. Let's get a new one from AAD.")
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scopes)

if "access_token" in result:
    access_token = result['access_token']  # JWT access token

    token = jwt.decode(access_token, verify=False)
    print(token['roles'])

    # Updating user's password
    pwd_change_payload = {
        'passwordProfile': {
            'password': "newpassword123$#@",
            'forceChangePasswordNextSignIn': False
        }
    }

    usr_pwd_update_resp = requests.patch(
        '%s/%s' % (users_endpoint, user_id),
        headers={
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data=json.dumps(pwd_change_payload)
    )

    resp_status_code = usr_pwd_update_resp.status_code

    if resp_status_code == 204:
        logging.info("Password successfully changed in Azure")

    elif resp_status_code == 403:
        print("ERROR 403")
        print(usr_pwd_update_resp)
    else:
        print("Unknown error?? " + str(resp_status_code) + ": " + str(usr_pwd_update_resp) )
else:
    print(result)
```

What exactly I need to configure on Azure side to make sure that the above code will work properly

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

to be able to change other user passwords you need and admin role such as the ones mentioned or others like [Authentication Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#authentication-administrator). Without those you won't be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To update the `passwordProfile` of the user, the `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` permission is needed. But it is the `Delegated permission`, not `Application permission`. It means the permission will not take effect in the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)(the [`confidential_client_secret_sample`](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/confidential_client_secret_sample.py) you provided uses it).

So if you want to let the `Delegated permission` take effect, you need to use a user-interactive way, e.g. [`interactive_sample`](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/interactive_sample.py), [`device_flow_sample`](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/device_flow_sample.py), [`username_password_sample`](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/username_password_sample.py)(not recommended and not work for MFA-enabled account). And you should note in these samples, they all use [`PublicClientApplication`](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/blob/e2ccb946592ef471a24d6e0b118e5a232701fc1e/sample/interactive_sample.py#L31), means you need to set `Allow public client flows` to `Yes` like below.

[image]

Besides, if you just want to avoid to use admin role because of the security issue, actually it is unnecessary, because the [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#helpdesk-administrator-permissions) of `Helpdesk Administrator` are less than the combination of `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` and `Directory.ReadWrite.All`, it is better to use `Helpdesk Administrator` role directly in this case.